# why does this works SOMETIMES in python ? (variable scope)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

This doesn't work: (global name 'a' is not defined)

```
if True:
  a = 3
else:
  a = 4
print a
```

This works:

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    if True:
      a = 3
    else:
      a = 4
    print a

A().f()
```

This doesn't work: (global name 'a' is not defined)

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    a = 3
  def f(self):
    print a

A().f()
```

Why is it working in one case and not in another ? I thought that if it works in case (2) then it is because `a` gets in the class context, but this doesn't make it work in (3)
I saw other discussions but I don't understand everything that is said and cases vary a bit.

EDIT:

example 1 does NOT work, at least in a python 2.7 interpreter. This is why it examples 1 and 2 are contradictory

Comment: The first example **does** work. `a` is always defined.

Comment: In your last example, `a` is a local variable in `__init__`. Local variables in functions are not visible outside of the function scope. It doesn't matter that both `f` and `__init__` are methods on the same class, they don't share their local namespaces.

Comment: @MartijnPieters First example does not work on my machine. I am using the interpreter, if it makes a difference

Comment: Of course example 1 works, in a Python 2.7 interpreter and everywhere else. There must be a different error (`==` instead of `=` maybe?)

Comment: Not the example you posted here; if it doesn't work in your interpreter, something is seriously broken, *or* you didn't run the code you posted here. The `if True:` branch is always going to be executed, and if it is not, then certainly the `else:` branch is. Both branches bind a value to the name `a`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a variable within a function, like this

```
  def __init__(self):
    a = 3
```

it will be accessible only within that function. That's why both 1 and 2 are working. In the third case, you creating a local variable in one function and trying to access it in another function where the variable is not visible. That's why it fails.

In order to make the third case working, add the variable to the current object (`self`), like this

```
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 3
```

And this has to be accessed with the current object only

```
  def f(self):
    print self.a
```

**Edit:**

Regarding the first statement, if you execute the `if..else` and the `print` statements like this, it works fine

```
>>> if True:
...     a = 3
... else:
...     a = 4
... 
>>> print a
3
```

Comment: Thanks, but please see edit. I know about `self.` to make a variable instance, but the question is completely different if you take into account that it doesnt work when tried in the interpreter

Comment: @Thomas Please check my edit in my solution, which shows that first case also produces valid output

Answer (score 1):

In the third example, `a` is a local variable in `__init__` and is discarded when that method ends. Within classes, you need to use `self.a` to keep it around:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 3
  def f(self):
    print self.a
```

Your other examples actually both work, because in both `a` is defined locally and printed within the same scope. To copy-paste example 1 from my interpreter (2.7.3):

```
>>> if True:
    a = 3
else:
    a = 4


>>> print a
3
```

Comment: Please see edit. I know about `self.` to make a variable instance, but the question is completely different if you take into account that it doesnt work when tried in the interpreter

Comment: I have pasted the exact result I get from the interpreter for example 1, no `NameError`